# How to Wire New Ceiling Fan with Remote and Wall Switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I wired my new ceiling fan to the picture attached. It was not working because the light stayed on all the time so I put the blue from the ceiling fan to the black and black from ceiling and receiver. That fixed the light issue but now the fan only works when the light switch is ON.

What wire to I need to change to make it so the fan works when the light switch is on and off?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: If you post a link to your picture I'll edit your question to include it

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 1):

So we have a couple of conventions here.  The conventions are suggestions.

> First, over on the wall/ceiling side, the "convention" is that black is always-hot, and red is switched-hot from a switch.
>
> Second, on the fan, there's another "convention": blue is light and black is fan.

So. The problem is that your ceiling wires did not follow the convention (nor are they required to). The instruction diagram assumed they did.  But in fact they are exchanged.  The black is switched and the red is always-hot.

Connect ceiling red to the input of the receiver.  Connect ceiling black to the lamp blue wire.    That should get you home.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the remote to control the light or fan? In your pic the red is the switch leg coming from the wall switch? If so I’m your pic the fan will be controlled by the wall switch and the light controlled by remote, as long as long as you are feeding the remote supply black with constant power?